# Elegant way for entity version numbers with postgresql and hibernate

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate, version

I want to introduce a version number for some entities. I'm using hibernate and postgresql. My requirements are

- Add a version column (BIGINT) to some tables
- Update a row's version on every insert/update
- Use a "global" (scope: schema) sequence for the version numbers
- So the version numbers are not gapless but sortable and unique (even among different tables of the schema)
- The version number is of course not the primary key or so

My current approch would use database triggers but I wonder if there is a more elegant way using either (postgre)sql or hibernate features.

Comment: If you use a SINGLE global sequence for multiple tables, then you'll necessarily have gaps.

Comment: Thanks for the hint :-) As stated in the question: "not gapless". This is totally okay for me.

Comment: Why do you want the version numbers to be sortable? This seems like an artificial requirement. Usually, you only want them to be different.

Comment: Sortable and unique are requirements, yes.